# dialogfragment обновить родительский фрагмент

Tags: java, android

есть фрагмент на котором есть три вкладки (табхост) с листвью на каждой вкладке, при нажатии на любой элемент списка выводится диалог фрагмент, в котором есть возможность перекидывать выбранный элемент в другую вкладку . Вопрос такой, как собственно обновить родительский фрагмент при изменении значения внутри диалог фрагмента?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А каким образом хранятся данные и как определяется в какой из вкладок какие данные показывать? В какой момент происходит загрузка дынных в список?

Comment: данные в базе данных, для каждого параметра (учу, знаю, без выбора) свой аргумент, данные переносятся с этим проблем нет, просто не знаю как обновить родительский фрагмент

Comment: Вот ответ на ваш вопрос на англо-саксонсом. Переводить сейчас времени нема. [DialogFragment and onDismiss](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23786151/3212712)